# Is toJSON supported in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome

when using JSON.stringify in Google Chrome it seems that toJSON isn't being called? I am using json2.js as a back-up for browsers that don't support it. I guess since Chrome supports JSON but not toJSON json2.js isn't being used at all?

**Update**
Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/GZzvZ/

Firefox: {"foo":"foo","bar":"bar"}
Chrome: {"bar":"bar"}

Comment: Please submit your code so we can identify the cause of error.

Comment: Added an example. Now I am doubting if I am using toJSON correctly though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var t = {};

t.toJSON = function () { alert('meuh'); return (''); }
JSON.stringify(t)
```

Works perfectly fine for me.
It does alert, so it does call the toJSON method appropriately (in Chrome 8).

EDIT:

That's **normal**. Your Foo is a  function, and function objects are not allowed in JSON. Firefox is just being forgiving, I guess.

Well, actually I wonder, I don't find a clear answer in the standard. Considering you supply a toJSON() to provide your own serialization, should it be allowed or not. But anyway, that's the reason for your failure.

If you edit your jsFiddle example like this, the `toJSON` is called accordingly on `foo`.

```
var obj = function(){
    this.foo = 'test'; // OK
    //this.foo = function(){ }; KO
    this.foo.toJSON = function(){
        return 'foo';  
    };

    this.bar = 'bar';
}

var ins = new obj();
var json = JSON.stringify( ins );
document.write( json );
```